# How do I install the Noise Repellent plugin, for Ardour, in Ubuntu Studio 20.10?

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-studio, ardour

I moved to Ubuntu Studio 20.10 in October to take advantage of Jack and Ardour for podcast editing. I'm newer to Linux, but I am getting comfortable in Terminal.

I moved from Audacity, but Audacity has an effect called noise reduction, and the only similar lv2 plugin I've found is called Noise Repellent. [See their Github page](https://github.com/lucianodato/noise-repellent).

I have spent days trying to install this plugin and have failed many times and in many ways and I just can't figure it out. I'm posting in the Ardour Discourse next, but perhaps there is someone here who has run into this issue.

I've done a few "git clones" successfully, so I tried to build this using the exact directions on the GitHub page. When it tries to build I get a few errors, you can see below.

Screenshot of the terminal window with a few errors:

[image: Screenshot of terminal window with a few errors]

TLDR is Program sord_validate found: NO and Run-time dependency fftw3f found: NO (tried pkconfig and cmake)

I can't find anything about a sord_validate program, but when I look up fftw3f I get pretty scary messages about don't do this unless you are an advanced user. OK.

I asked a friend who knows more and they suggested I just download the zip file and unzip it in the correct directory where the lv2 plugins are located, so I did that.

I was able to open Ardour, scan for new plugins, find Noise Repellent, then try to add that plugin to a track, it appeared in the plugin manager window, but when I try to add it to the track, I got an error message. The Plugin Noise Repellent could not be loaded, check the log files.

When I checked the log file, the error said “Failed to Instantiate Plug in”.

I'm lost. It seems like it should be so easy to add additional plugins into Ardour, and that since Ubuntu Studio would already have a build ready to go. In Audacity, it is EASY to add additional effects. It's strange that a background noise reducing plugin is not ALREADY packed in the Ardour with the other lv2 plugins it comes with.

Is there another way I'm supposed to be doing this? I'm posting in Ardour next and then trying to contact the dev. Everything else has been so much easier since moving to Ubuntu Studio but this has been torturous, so perhaps I'm doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing one of the build dependencies to satisfy the need for fftw3, do this:

```
apt install libfftw3-dev
```

You may also need `sordi` for the `sord_validate` error.

```
apt install sordi
```

Comment: Thanks, but I made an even more basic error, than that, My Bad, Journey Into Lin-OOPS. I was trying to compile bc I couldn't get the zip download to work properly. I downloaded the wrong zip file. There was one called AMD64, I thought, I don't have AMD I am on Intel and NVIDIA, so I downloaded the x386, not knowing that meant the 32 bit version, so it wouldn't work on my 64 bit architecture. *Smackshead*

Comment: Meaning once I downloaded the actual correct zip, put the extracted file in the right place, it now shows up in Ardour, and I can repel noise finally